# How to set up VirtualBox Host-only Adapter on Debian 9 guest OS?

Tags: debian, networking, virtualbox

I have created a VirtualBox VM, which is running Debian 9 as the guest OS, and it can connect to the internet successfully using the default NAT network interface.

We also need the web server and ssh server in the VM to be accessible from the host computer OS (Windows 10, if relevant), but not from the internet at large. When another colleague asked me to set up a similar VM some time ago (but with Debian 8 and Windows 7, respectively), after much experimentation, it seemed that creating an additional **Host-only Adapter** in the guest OS, and updating the `hosts` file on the host OS to map the hostname set up in the VM guest OS to its (private) IP address "just worked".

However, I don't seem to be having similar success with Debian 9, perhaps because the way that networking is now set up seems to have changed?

The NAT interface appears as `enp0s3` with private IP 10.0.2.15, and it can connect to the internet, but a web browser or ssh on the host OS cannot see this address.

If I shutdown the VM and add an additional Host-only network adapter, when I reboot the VM, I now have an additional interface called `enp0s8`, but it is "down" and does not have an IP address associated with it.

Do I need to do something else to set up this interface, or is VirtualBox supposed to take care of it?

Answer (score 4):

I followed the instructions here: https://dev.to/isabolic99/how-to-set-host-only-adapter-on-vm-virtual-box-2jka . It has instructions about adding additional Host Network settings, but I just went with the default, and it worked fine.

Here are the steps I took:

- Add a Host-Only Network Adapter to your Debian 9 guest vm.
- Boot into the vm guest, and determine the name of the new network adapter

  `$ ls /sys/class/net`

Mine was `enp0s8`.

- List item

Add the following to your `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto enp0s8
allow-hotplug enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
address 192.168.56.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

- restart your vm, or use the `ifup enp0s8` command.

Now, from your host machine, you should be able to access the vbox guest at `192.168.56.11` on all the standard ports.

Comment: Thanks, adding `auto enp0s8 allow-hotplug enp0s8` did the job for me on VirtualBox 6.5 with Debian 10 guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

A Host only network in VirtualBox parlance, is a interface for talking the VM to talk with the host machine. (e.g. an internal/isolated network).

As such, it won't get an IP address alone. One of the possibilities is defining a network manually with static IP addresses, that is not used in your internal network, such as 192.168.x.1/30 for the host side, and 192.168.x.2/30 for the VM side.